# vb.net regex.matches not returning all matches

Tags: php, regex, vb.net, preg-match-all

```
Dim pattern As String = "^[ \t]*(\d+)[ \t]*(#[^#]*#)?[ \t]*(\w+)[ \t]?(.*)$"
Dim sentence As String = "9 #Left# Itema Desc"

For Each match As Match In Regex.Matches(sentence, pattern)
  Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}' at position {1}", match.Value, match.Index)
Next
```

only returns:

Found '9 #Left# Itema Desc' at position 0

Testing the vb pattern above using Expresso returns:

1: 9

2: #left#

3: Itema

4: Desc

In addition this PHP regex also returns the four items:

```
preg_match_all('/^[ \t]*(\d+)[ \t]*(#[^#]*#)?[ \t]*(\w+)[ \t]?(.*)$/m', $in, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks in advance!

Thanks to Ark-kun indeed my problem was groups - here's code that works:

```
Dim pattern As String = "^[ \t]*(\d+)[ \t]*(#[^#]*#)?[ \t]*(\w+)[ \t]?(.*)$"
Dim sentence As String = "9 #Left# Itema Desc"

Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(sentence, pattern)
If match.Success Then
  Console.WriteLine("Matched text: {0}", match.Value)
    For ctr As Integer = 1 To match.Groups.Count - 1
      Console.WriteLine("   Group {0}:  {1}", ctr, match.Groups(ctr).Value)
    Next
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The result is logically correct. You've written the "whole line" regex and the `Regex.Matches` method found a single match - the whole line.
What you probably want is the `match.Captures` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures.aspx